# Expand partial delta timeseries into full historical timeseries

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres with timeseries data. The table contains multiple versions (releases) of the same timeseries. The same data point can have different values in different releases due to historical revisions and changes in forecasts. For those data points where there is no difference in a newer release, we only store the original data point.

A simplified example is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_timeseries
(
    series_id integer NOT NULL,
    release_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    value_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "value" numeric,
    CONSTRAINT test_timeseries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (series_id, release_date, value_date)
)
```

with the following records:

```
INSERT INTO test_timeseries VALUES (1, '2023-02-01', '2023-01-01', 1)
INSERT INTO test_timeseries VALUES (1, '2023-02-01', '2023-02-01', 2)
INSERT INTO test_timeseries VALUES (1, '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', 3)
INSERT INTO test_timeseries VALUES (1, '2023-02-01', '2023-04-01', 4)
INSERT INTO test_timeseries VALUES (1, '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01', 5)
```

In this situation, I have managed to write a query to retrieve a specific full history for any release_date by combining the unchanged data points with the deltas (the data points that are different in a new release). I can do so with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (series_id, value_date) 
    series_id,
    (SELECT max(release_date) AS max_release_date
           FROM silver.test_timeseries WHERE DATE(release_date) <= '2023-03-01') AS release_date,
    value_date,
    "value"
FROM silver.test_timeseries
ORDER BY series_id, value_date, release_date DESC;
```

Now what I need help with, is what if I want to expand all timeseries in a single query, so for this specific case I would like to return the full timeseries for `2023-02-01` and `2023-03-01`.

NB: The data provided is just a simplified example. The query needs to work for more than two releases, and there can be multiple series_ids as well all representing different timeseries.

EDIT: what I would like the above described query to return is the following:

```
(1, '2023-02-01', '2023-01-01', 1)
(1, '2023-02-01', '2023-02-01', 2)
(1, '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', 3)
(1, '2023-02-01', '2023-04-01', 4)
(1, '2023-03-01', '2023-01-01', 1)
(1, '2023-03-01', '2023-02-01', 2)
(1, '2023-03-01', '2023-03-01', 3)
(1, '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01', 5)
```

Comment: a calender table, which you generate once will be the simplest solution, but for dynamic solution you will find al lot of examples here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached this by noticing that the result you were after was the same as you might get if you repeatedly executed your original query for each distinct release_date and used UNION to return all the resulting rows.

You can do this more cleanly by using a common table expression to identify each distinct release date, and using a full join from this to your test_timeseries table to achieve a similar result:

```
WITH 
rel_dates as (
  SELECT DISTINCT release_date FROM test_timeseries
  )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (series_id, release_date, value_date) 
    series_id,
    (SELECT max(release_date) AS max_release_date
           FROM test_timeseries WHERE DATE(release_date) <= rel_dates.release_date) AS release_date,
    value_date,
    "value"
FROM test_timeseries
JOIN rel_dates ON TRUE
ORDER BY series_id, release_date DESC, value_date;
```

DB fiddle here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0

Comment: Awesome Matt, that's spot on. Great concept to understand as well repeatedly executing the query with the JOIN, I'm sure that will come in handy on something else in the future. Thanks a lot!